# Security issue of database files saved in data/data - Android

Tags: android, security

A security scanning app has identified some sensitive data that was saved in the app's `data/data` directory. Upon investigating which files were detected, they were from other 3rd party libraries. Though these files can only be accessed via rooted or devices with USB Debugging enabled.

The paths were:
`/data/data/com.my.app/databases/com.thirdparty.lib`

another one was from Google's Firebase library
`/data/data/com.my.app/databases/.com.google.firebase.crashlytics.../open-sessions/.../keys`

Is there a way to secure these files or the directory, or is it up to these 3rd party libraries to secure them? Any other recommendations?

Comment: "Is there a way to secure these files or the directory" -- secure against *what*? As you noted, they are already inaccessible to everything except your application code and rooted device users.